# Заполнение строки в которой уже есть запись

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте интересует такой вопрос, а можно ли продолжить заполнять строку в которой уже есть информация?
Допустим:

```
string str;
cin>>str;    /// ввели допустим 111
cout<<"Какая либо запись на экран"<<endl;
cin>>str;  ///продолжаем вводить строку str, тоесть мы к 111 еще добавляем какую-либо запись, например 222
cout<<str; /// 111222
```

Можно ли такое вообще реализовать? И можно ли при в вводе str во второй раз выводилось на консоль то что мы уже записали при вводе в первый раз и дополнять записью которую мы вводим ?

Comment: Оператор `>>(istream&,string&)` *перезаписывает* строку, так что непосредственно так не получится. Надо писать в другую строку и добавлять к первой.